# Function Creating Array of Spans Always Returns Undefined

Tags: javascript, android-webview

I have a method which returns an array of spans of a given id pattern. This array does get created and all the proper elements appear to be in it when I test by print out the values of the array at the end of the function.

This is the function:

```
function getAllSpansForID(sectionID) {
    var foundAllSpans = false,
        i = 1,
        spanID,
        span,
        spanArray = new Array();

    /* Keep looking until we found all the selection spans.*/

    while (!foundAllSpans) {
        spanID = sectionID + "-" + i;
        span = document.getElementById(spanID);

        /* 
        If we didn't get a span we can assume there are no more to find. 
        We are done with this loop.
        */
        if (span == null) {
            foundAllSpans = true;
            console.log("Found all spans.");
        }

        /* 
        Else, add the span to the array we are going to return.
        */
        else {
            spanArray[i-1] = span;
            i++;
        }
    }

    console.log("returning spanArray.length: " + spanArray.length);
    for (i = 0; i < spanArray.length; i++) {
        console.log("spanArray[i].id: " + spanArray[i].id);
        console.log("spanArray[i].outerHTML: " + spanArray[i].outerHTML);
    }

    return spanArray;
}
```

**My problem is that whenever I call this function the returned value is ALWAYS UNDEFINED.**

This code:

```
var spansArray = getAllSpansForID(verseID),
length = spansArray.length;
```

always produces this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: spansArrray is not defined
```

I have found many SIMILAR problems on SO with returnign arrays due to scoping problems but none to match my exact situation. I have tried altering this method, including using `spanArray.push(span)`, and `spanArray.push.apply(spanArray, span)` to add my spans, but to no avail. I am out of ideas.

Comment: Why is the function named one time getAllSpansForID and the other one getAllSelectionSpansForVerse ? Is that really the same ?

Comment: `spanArray !== spansArrray`

Comment: @Andreas They call it `spanArray` inside the function, and `spansArray` outside, so that should be fine.

Comment: Have you run it through a debugger, like the one in the Chrome development tools? Also, do you see any of the console messages?

Comment: @dystroy Typo, now fixed.

Comment: @greg84 I am running in Android/Eclipse, so I am not setup to run inside of Chrome. I do see the all the conosle messages in the debugger though.

Comment: I copy-pasted this into jsFiddle, and [it worked fine for me](http://jsfiddle.net/nYzLP/)

Comment: What do you see if you `console.log(spanArray)` right before you return it?

Comment: What's the markup and the value of `verseID`? The function works, so maybe it's the input? :)

Comment: @Bergi Doing the exact line you provided prints this output: `[object HTMLElement]`

Comment: @greg84 I do not entirely doubt it, verseID is a string with a format like this: _sxx.xx.xx, where x is a base 10 digit. I am hesitant to think that is the problem, only because I get real `<span>` elements when using `document.getElementById(spanID)`

Comment: @Jon: Everything seems right then. Only the variable name in the error message has 3 `r`s. Did you fix that as well?

Comment: @Bergi It looks like you might have caught this before I did. If you post what you just said as I question I will accept it as the right answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the error message I can spot an `r` too much:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: spansArrray is not defined
                               ^^^
```

Seems to be another typo, not in the code you posted here but in the one you executed…

Answer (score 0):

change to:

```
var spansArray = getAllSpansForID(verseID);
var length = spansArray.length;
```

Comment: All right, that would fix OP's typo as well :-) But there's no functional difference from what he posted in his question.

Answer (score 0):

***D'OH!!***

As you can see by my error message, `spansArrray` (3 r's) is undefined. I defined `spansArray` (2 r's). I fixed and all works well. Just a typo....

I did not lift `length = spansArray.length;`  straight from the code but rather just wrote it out, so the code posted here would not have failed.

Sorry everyone. I appreciate all the help just the same!!!